# How can I print descending numbers on left side and ascending numbers on the bottom side of a box?

Tags: c++

I have written codes to print a box with # outline but I am trying to print out a box which looks something exactly like that instead:

```
 # # # # # # # # # # # 
8#                   #
7#                   #         
6#                   #
5#                   #
4#                   #
3#                   #
2#                   #
1#                   #
0#                   #
 # # # # # # # # # # #
   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

The codes I currently have and the output attached image:

```
int i = Xend;
int j = Yend;
int side = Yend;           // Yend is = 8;
for (i = 0; i < Xend; i++) // Xend is = 8;
{
    for (j = 0; j < side; j++) // Ystart is 0;
    {
        if (i == 0 || i == side - 1 || j == 0 || j == side - 1)
        {
            cout << "#"
                 << " ";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "  ";
        }
    }
    cout << "\n";
}
```

[current code output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvA8w.png)

Comment: Begin by just writing out the value of `i` at the beginning of each line. Then decide how to skip the first and last line (which will have only `#`). Then figure out how to count down instead of up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am very sorry. But I have to do this . . .

There are that many potential solutions and here is one of them:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>

constexpr std::string_view box(R"(
 # # # # # # # # # # # 
8#                   #
7#                   #
6#                   #
5#                   #
4#                   #
3#                   #
2#                   #
1#                   #
0#                   #
 # # # # # # # # # # #
   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
)");

int main() {

    std::cout << box;
}
```

You can also do programatically:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
int main() {

    // Print upper box row
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; ++i)
        std::cout << " #";
    std::cout << '\n';

    // Now print out 9 rows with number and left and right box delimiter
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
        std::cout << (8 - i) << '#';
        for (int k = 0; k < 9; ++k) std::cout << "  ";
        std::cout << " #\n";
    }

    // Print lower box row
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; ++i)
        std::cout << " #";
    std::cout << '\n';

    // Print row with numbers
    std::cout << "   ";
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: I have a text files of coordinates [link](https://pastebin.pl/view/81bd1d8b) is it possible to mark them in the box like in the attached screenshot? [link](https://ibb.co/x1qQmbW)

Answer (score 0):

Slighty more generic answer which will work for 1-9 rows. You could make it work for all sizes if you fiddle with the padding and make it conditional on number of digits used.

```
int numX = 8;
int numY = 8;
int Yincrementer = 0;
const int Xend = numX + 3;
const int Yend = numY + 3;

for (int i = Xend; i >= 0; i--) {
    for (int j = 0; j < Yend; j++) {

        //Handle top and bottom lines
        if (i == Xend || i == 1) {
            if (j == 0) {
                std::cout << " # ";
            }
            else if (j == Yend - 1) {
                std::cout << "#";
            }
            else {
                std::cout << "# ";
            }
        }
        
        //Handle numerical bottom line
        else if (i == 0) {
            if (j == 0 || j == 1) {
                std::cout << " ";
            }
            else {
                if (Yincrementer <= numY) {
                    std::cout << " " << Yincrementer;
                    Yincrementer++;
                }
            }
        }

        //Handle grid lines
        else{
            if (j == 0) {
                if (numX >= 0) {
                    std::cout << numX << "# ";
                    numX--;
                }
                else {
                    std::cout <<  " # ";
                }
            }
            else if (j == Yend -1) {
                std::cout << "#";
            }
            else {
                std::cout << "  ";
            }
        }
    }
}
```